# Content-Type must be application/json error with python 2.7.5 and couch DB 1.30

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, couchdb

I'm running Python 2.7.5 and couchDB 1.3.0 on Win7 (64) and get an error message when I save a JSON document: couchdb.http.ServerError: (415, (u'bad_content_type', u'Content-Type must be application/json')).
...

```
kkey = 'schluessel'
vvalue = 'Wert'
str1 = [kkey , vvalue]
str2 = json.dumps(str1)
oup.write(str2 + '\n')
# the line above gives: ["schluessel", "Wert"] 
doc_id, doc_rev = db.save(str2)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

At first you're trying to save not JSON document, which is represented by JSON object type, but JSON array which isn't a document at all. Try this instead:

```
kkey = 'schluessel'
vvalue = 'Wert'
str1 = {kkey: vvalue}
str2 = json.dumps(str1)
oup.write(str2 + '\n')
# the line above gives: {"schluessel": "Wert"}
doc_id, doc_rev = db.save(str2)
```